# HTML items not changing while after running the server

Tags: meteor, windows-7

I am doing a Course on meteor from Coursera. The teacher uses a mac or a linux in the installation so its becoming difficult for me to follow up.

After running the server, the teacher changed a few `HTML` items in the code and it changed on the server but when I change anything after starting and running the server, the file does not get changed.

```
<head>
  <title>image_share</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Coursera!</h1>
  <div class="container">
  {{> images}}
</div>
</body>

<template name="images">
    <div class="row">
  {{#each images}}
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">

        <img class="js-image" src="{{img_src}}" 
        alt="{{img_alt}}"/> 

        <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>description of the image</p>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  {{/each}}
</div> <!-- / row -->
  </template>
```

My edited code,

```
<head>
  <title>image_share</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My world!</h1>
  <div class="container">
  {{> images}}
</div>
</body>

<template name="images">
    <div class="row">
  {{#each images}}
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">

        <img class="js-image" src="{{img_src}}" 
        alt="{{img_alt}}"/> 

        <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>description of the image</p>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- / col -->
  {{/each}}
</div> <!-- / row -->
  </template>
```

Notice I have changed the contents of `<h1>` tag but still nothing changes on the server.

Comment: Have you try to restart the server?

Comment: you want to look into `live-reload` if you want an automate refresh

Comment: any errors in the server console?